# How to plot exp-functions using r

Tags: r, plot, exp

I want to plot two e-functions (in a single graph) using R:

a) `f(t)=20(1-e^(-0,1t))`

b) `f(t)=0,4t(t+7)e^(-0,1t)`

I tried the `curve()` function but I don't know how to use it with e-functions.

Could you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? Please share the code, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44343278/edit

Comment: `f <- function(t) 20*(1-exp(-0.1*t));
plot(f, from= -3, to=10)`

Comment: or `curve(20*(1-exp(-0.1*x)), -50, 50)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the help file of `?curve`, you can find many clues, e.g.

```
chippy <- function(x) sin(cos(x)*exp(-x/2))
curve(chippy, -8, 7, n = 2001)
```

which would, in your case, translate to

```
f1 <- function(t) 20 * (1-exp(-0.1 * t))
curve(f1, from = -10, to = 20)
```

I'll let you figure out how to do the second one.